# Images not loading on Outlook but work when in Litmus test

Tags: html, html-table, outlook, html-email

I'm testing a new HTMl email which is built through tables. It renders fine on Litmus check for all Outlook versions, but when I send a test email to myself in Outlook, the image doesn't show? I'm not sure why this is happening? Ideas?

**Here is my simple table:**

```html
<table style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;border:1px solid #bfbfbf;background-color:#e8ecef;mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px" align="center" valign="top" width="593" class="column column-0 of-1 empty" bgcolor="#e8ecef" cellpadding="0"
  cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="columns--column-content" bgcolor="#e8ecef" style="background-color:#e8ecef;padding:0;">
        <div id="hs_cos_wrapper_section_one" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_rich_text" style="color: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: inherit;" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="rich_text">
          <table class="wrapper" style="table-layout: fixed; mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-type="image">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table class="wrapper" style="table-layout: fixed; mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-type="image">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" align="center" valign="top">
                          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial,Helvectica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px;" target="_blank" data-hs-link-id="0">
                          <img src="https://content.liveres.co.uk/hubfs/Emails/Newsletter/Zonal/The-Bottom-Line.jpg?t=1517929358720" width="100%" border="0" style="display: block; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">                            </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="height: 118px;">
                <td style="height: 118px;" align="center">
                  <table class="module" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 360px; mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" border="0" width="360" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-type="text">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0px 20px 0 20px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 38px; color: #535353; text-align: center;" valign="top" bgcolor="">Heading</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center">
                  <table class="module" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 360px; mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" border="0" width="360" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-type="text">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 18px; color: #414042; text-align: center;" valign="top">Text here.</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit**: This issue is for Microsoft Office Outlook 2010.

Comment: For me, outlook blocks images and shows a `! This email contains images, click here to show these` or something along these lines right above the email itself. Clicking this shows the images. I think there is a setting in outlook to have it always show images, but by default it blocks them.

Comment: Do you get the option to see the images in outlook? Or no? Do they just disappear?

Comment: @Tyler - Yeah, that's what I thought, I have buttons in each table which are also images. They show fine, it just doesn't show the header images for some reason.

Comment: @scoopzilla Nope, the image just doesn't load at all.

Comment: try http instead of https

Comment: I didn't even see that. Yeah that is probably the solution

Comment: @Horen but the domain of the website has SSL enabled. So why would 'https' not work? The thing is, I also have buttons which are images. Their src is https and they load fine? It's just the header images which do not?

Answer (score 1):

It happens for me when I test with relative paths, local images. As soon as you use the absolute path to their hosted files, they should show. Alternatively, you can try removing the height from the img tag, that also makes them show up.